# C# p/invoke C method returning a byte*

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I got a C dll where one of the functions has the following signature:

```
DLLExport byte* DecodeData(CDecoderApp* decoderApp, HWND handle, byte* data, int length, int* frameLength, int* waveDataLength, int* decodedFrameSize, int* channels, int* frequency)
```

I need to p/invoke this method and tried the following:

```
[DllImport("Decoder.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern byte[] DecodeData(IntPtr decoderApp, IntPtr handle, byte[] data, int length, out int frameLength, out int waveDataLength, out int decodedFrameSize, out int channels, out int frequency);
```

Which doesn't work as I guess that c# doesn't know the size of the byte array.

How should I solve this so I can get the returned byte array ?

Comment: You'll have to use IntPtr instead, then Marshal.Copy() to get it into a managed array.  Do beware that there is a severe memory management problem, somebody is going to have to release the returned unmanaged array and that somebody cannot be you.

Comment: @HansPassant could you please show a code sample on how to do it ?

Comment: You just need to call [`Marshal.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx). I don’t think there is any other magic behind it. I.e. allocated a byte array of the correct size, call your external function, pass the pointer to `Marshal.Copy` to get the data into your byte array, and finally call some other external function to free that memory again.

Comment: @poke You say allocate a byte array of the correct size but I've no idea how big the array is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The marshaller cannot, as you suspect, marshal a return value of type `byte[]`. You will need to do the marshalling yourself. Change the return value to be of type `IntPtr`:

```
[DllImport("Decoder.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern IntPtr DecodeData(
    IntPtr decoderApp, 
    IntPtr handle, 
    byte[] data, 
    int length, 
    out int frameLength, 
    out int waveDataLength, 
    out int decodedFrameSize, 
    out int channels, 
    out int frequency
);
```

Call the function like this:

```
IntPtr decodedDataPtr = DecodeData(...);
```

Check for errors:

```
if (decodedDataPtr == IntPtr.Zero)
    // handle error
```

Presumably one of the parameters, perhaps `waveDataLength` contains the length of the byte array that is returned:

```
byte[] decodedData = new byte[waveDataLength];
Marshal.Copy(decodedDataPtr, decodedData, 0, waveDataLength);
```

Of course, now you are left holding a pointer to memory that the unmanaged code allocated. You will need to find a way to deallocate that memory. Perhaps the memory is allocated on a shared heap. Perhaps the unmanaged code exports a deallocator. But with the information that we have, we cannot tell you precisely how to deallocate it.